# How to reapply failed sql Scripts with Flyway

Tags: flyway

I am trying flyway for first time, evaluating how it will fit into our project.
Trying to understand how a **Failed** Scenario will work

[image]

Naturally, what i did next was, modified the sql script, and re tried running, but got checksum error
[image]

Have three Ques here

1. So I guess the only way out is ... need to make a 1.2 with correct format or manually modify 'schema_version' table. Right , or am i missing something?
2. Wondering how will such a scenario work in case if this script is called from continuous integration tools (*Jenkins* or *Bamboo*). Manual Intervention will be needed.
3. Not sure if some other tool like Liquibase will behave in a different (better) manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that situation I think you should use "flyway repair" rather the "flyway migrate"

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair

One thing from your post that is not clear is was the script you ran a single DDL statement or a number of statements, of which one or more failed?. The reason for asking is that flyway records the results of a migration, but does not itself clean up 'script errors'. Depending on the database you are using this could be done by running the DDL statements within a transaction.

Liquibased operates with a much tighter connection to the database as it directly interacts with the DDL that can be expressed in a range of different formats. As such it has a much tighter control over the management of DDL deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. As i was trying things out so i had one single DDL statement. but yes in real projects it will be more than DDL (or DML) statement... not sure is there a short sweet tutorial u can help me with, with some real project scenarios...

Comment: Sorry I'm only a few days ahead of you in terms of getting my head around flyway and so far I've not found many examples.

Answer (score 1):

Upstream insists on manual rolling back of failed migration and re-applying it again. There is no "skip" command.

But you can manually fix and complete failed migration and manually change `"schema_version"."success"` to `1`.

Comment: It will at least consider it as if the migration was successful and then the server will start without any exception